# Trying to find word in string but getting enumeration yields no result

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I am having 1 long string in which i want to find word starting with `Emp` **only after dot** in my string and if match then extract **that part after dot**.

Below is my string:

```
Value.EmployeeRFID,Value.EmployeeRFID1,Value.EmkhasisGFTR,Value.EmployeeGHID,Value.EmployeeFCKJ
```

Now in my above input i just want to extract only part after dot(`Foreg:EmployeeRFID,EmployeeRFID1 etc`) and i want to add that in below list:

```
var list= new List<string>();
```

**Expected output in above list variable:**

```
[0]:EmployeeRFID ,[1]=EmployeeRFID1, [2]:EmployeeGHID, [3]:EmployeeFCKJ
```

This is how i am trying with linq but i am getting `Enumeration yielded no results`:

```
string str="Value.EmployeeRFID,Value.EmployeeRFID1,Value.EmkhasisGFTR,Value.EmployeeGHID,Value.EmployeeFCKJ";

var data= str.Where(t=>t.ToString().StartsWith("Emp")).Select(t=>t.t.ToString()) // Enumeration yielded no results
```

Comment: Look into Regular Expressions - Maybe using a pattern along the lines of `\.(Emp[^, ]+)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you see any substring here that starts with "Origin"?

Comment: @Steve:Updated my query but got same output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try *regular expressions*:

```
  string source = "Value.EmployeeRFID,...,Value.EmployeeGHID,Value.EmployeeFCKJ";
  string pattern = @"(?<=\.)Emp\w*";

  string[] result = Regex.Matches(source, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Test:

```
  // EmployeeRFID
  // EmployeeRFID1
  // EmployeeGHID
  // EmployeeFCKJ
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: Ok this is working but is this possible that when matching Emp word if i have emp then also it should match because in 1 part of string when i got Value.employeeRFID then i didnt got employee.RFID

Comment: @Learning: just add `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option (see my edit)

Comment: Perfect.Thank you so much for your kind help and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 3):

`string` as an argument to LINQ extensions is an `IEnumerable<char>`, so your `t` is only one character. You probably meant to do something like this:

```
var data= str.Split('.')
             .Where(t => t.StartsWith("Emp")).Select(t => t.Split(',').First())
             .ToList();
```

But regular expressions as suggested by [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38900945/5528593) seem to be a better approach for string parsing than LINQ.

Comment: Working fine.Thank you so much for your kind  help and please keep helping like this :)